# Collapse when calling dismissModalViewController in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I use this in a function of table's parent view to show the tableview:

```
-(IBAction)someFunc{
   UITableViewController* controller = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
   [self presentModalViewController:controller];
   [controller release]
}
```

and after calling dismissModalViewController in the `UITableView`'s `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method,
the parent view will show a second and then the program collapses.

Comment: When you say "collapses" at the end there, do you mean that it crashes?

Comment: Yeah, crash! Is collapse different from crush?

Comment: @user465191: Can you please post your code here? So that we can help you out.

Comment: @user465191: Also try `Clean` and `Build` and see if there are some warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run under the debugger, look in the console.  Likely something was not retained.  Put a breakpoint on in table's parent view's viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear (probably in the latter).  Likely referencing an object that was released.

Comment: I got it, I found an array which I forgot to allocate.